# Elegant way of switching values inside a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of multi-valued tuples. The objective is to change tuples based on a variable value. Is there an elegant way to do it. The easiest way is to brute-force if-elseif statements but that makes the code long and repetitive.

```
list = [
    ('category',  'Categories',   personal_categories_page(user=userName),  'Show categories'),
    ('calendar',  'Calendar',     person_calendar(userName), 'Calendar View for %s' %displayName),
    ('user_area', 'Main User Db', user_area_mode(userName), 'Main User Area'),
]
```

Lets say in this scenario I would like to switch out calendar tuple based on an external variable displayname that can take very many values. Whats the pythonic way to do so. Would list comprehension work?

**Constraint**: I cannot change the data structure. It has to be a list of tuples

Comment: How can we __switch__ the tuple? What do you mean?

Comment: By switching I mean changing the values of the tuple. Much like a switch statement for a variable but only in this case we have a list of tuples and I want to change values inside one particular tuple

Comment: im not entirely sure what the question is ... but im pretty sure the answer is *use  a dict*

Comment: No. I just wan to change the values in a tuple based on some variable. So lets say if displayname is x then the tuple is (a,b,c) but if its y then the tuple is (d,e,f). I also have to know the tuple. I n my case its the tuple with string 'calender' that needs to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with a comprehension and a function:

```
def transform(t):
    if <this is not a tuple to be messed with>:
        return t
    return <mangled tuple>

list2 = [transform(x) for x in list1]
```

or if the test and transform are particularly simple, all inline:

```
list2 = [(<transformed x> if <test> else x) for x in list1]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is more in line with what I was thinking

Answer (score 4):

The pythonic solution would be to store them in a more appropriate data structure, such as a dictionary. Then it'd be trivial to change individual items.

```
pages = {
    'category':  ('Categories',   personal_categories_page(user=userName),  'Show categories'),
    'calendar':  ('Calendar',     person_calendar(userName), 'Calendar View for %s' %displayName),
    'user_area': ('Main User Db', user_area_mode(userName), 'Main User Area'),
}
```

Comment: ahhh I just sort of put this as a comment :P +1 good suggestion

Comment: This defintely works but unfortunatley in my particular case I am unable to change the data structure :(

Comment: Also, this assumes that there exists only one tuple with each first element).